# Email forwarding by domain

Tags: windows, email, exchange, iis-8

Can sense.com ( domain) receive all email and then forward to newtest.com(another domain)?
For example, sent email to  abc@sense.com , by the DNS, email will transfer to @sense.com first. And then seeking mailbox “abc”.
So can we forward all received email in sense.com to newtest.com(abc@sense.com forward to abc@newtest.com), even though abc@sense.com doesn’t exist. Server can directly forward the mail to newtest.com (just change the domain name).

P.S. both domain exist.

Domain Server Type:Microsoft-IIS/8.0 
Would like to use Microsoft Exchange service

Comment: If you want answers applicable to your situation, it would help if you told us what mailserver you're actually using.

Answer (score 0):

With `sendmail`, one can have a `virtusertable` entry that reads

```
@sense.com  %1@newtest.com
```

that will accomplish what you want.  Because you don't specify your MTA of choice, it's hard to know whether that's of any help to you.  Note also that if the `MX` for `newtest.com` is on a different box, and that box checks SPF on inbound email, you'll also need to arrange for `SRS` (or an equivalent) to rewrite the envelope-From, to prevent the destination `MX` from rejecting many of the emails out of hand.

**Edit**: the above will forward email originally destined for, eg, `fred@sense.com` to `fred@newtest.com` regardless of whether `fred@sense.com` is a valid user or not.  If `fred@newtest.com` is a valid user, delivery will complete; otherwise, a bounce will be generated.

**Edit 2**: not in the slightest, no; sendmail is a free MTA that runs on UNIX platforms.  If you'd made it clear at the beginning that you were using MS Exchange, I could have saved both our time by saying nothing, since I know nothing at all about MS Exchange.

Comment: all account should be created  in the domain sense.com in order to forward to newtest.com. What if a email account (name@sense.com) not exist in sense.com. But name@newtest.com is existing. Can it still forward the email name@sense.com to name@newtest.com?

Comment: See my edit above.

Comment: Is it applicable to Server Type :Microsoft-IIS/8.0 ?